# RSelenium add Extension to Firefox Profile in R

Tags: r, selenium, rselenium

I am trying to add a firefox profile to rselenium that adds an extension. Here is what i have come up with so far:

```
library("RSelenium")
startServer()
fprof <- makeFirefoxProfile(list(add.extension = "C:/selenium/save_text_to_file-2.7.1-fx.xpi"))
#mybrowser <- remoteDriver()
mybrowser <- remoteDriver(extraCapabilities = fprof)
mybrowser$open()
mybrowser$navigate("http://www.google.com")
```

I do not get an error but firefox opens without the plugin being installen or loaded. How can I add the plugin to firefox correctly?